# Multiple Android application install from Google Play

Tags: android

I have two different Android mobile application. One is already developed and One I am developing. Now what I want Whenever anyone wants to install my developed application from the Google Play than both the application should be Installed.
Please suggest how it will be possible.

Comment: have you already experienced this kind of thing?

Comment: You can ideally and legally only direct the user to the google play store to the other application. You cannot install both on install of any one of them

Comment: I want to install from Google Play only. For exp:-I want to do like any main app required some supporting apps.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to acquire Alphabet (Google's parent company), then order the developers of the Play Store to add this capability. Otherwise, what you want is not supported.

If you want all of this functionality to be installed, put it in one app, not two.